# Is it possible to make a gnome-shell window uncloseable

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Is it possible to make a gnome-shell gnome-terminal window uncloseable?

For example even if the "X" is clicked or even if the user types "exit" at the prompt the window does not close (in the latter case the terminal would restart).

Answer (score 0):

These are two different questions.

For clicking on "X": No, it's not possible. However, if there's any subcommand running inside (not just your shell directly launched by `gnome-terminal`), a confirmation dialog is presented before closing the terminal.

For typing "exit": Yes, this is possible. Go to Profile Preferences -> Command, and set When command exits: Restart or Hold (whichever you prefer).